# 2 Column Flexbox Grid on mobile

Tags: html, css

Apologies for the noob question!

I have an a 8 column flexbox grid which displays as follows on large devices.

https://s14.postimg.org/ixpybtxmn/desktop-grid.jpg

However, on mobile it currently displays like this.

https://s14.postimg.org/dddh1mm1d/mobile.jpg

Here is a stripped down version of my code

```
`https://codepen.io/igosean/pen/rdrgZP`
```

What i want is the grid to stack to two columns at 50% width on mobile.
If anyone could help i would be grateful.

Comment: Provide your code .

Comment: Try to use flex-wrap: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself.** NB - **Please don't abuse the code blocks to get around this requirement**.

Comment: Apologies, i will update this shortly!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
.flex-grid {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 0 40px 0;
  
}

.col img { 
  max-width: 200px;
}

.flex-grid .col {
  flex: 1;
}

@media (max-width: 900px) {
  .flex-grid {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  .flex-grid .col {
      flex: 1;
      width: 50%;
      margin: 0 0 10px 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-grid">
       <div class="col"><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2503/1376/files/artificial.jpg?3140817636037500562"></div>
              <div class="col"><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2503/1376/files/artificial.jpg?3140817636037500562"></div>
              <div class="col"><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2503/1376/files/artificial.jpg?3140817636037500562"></div>
              <div class="col"><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2503/1376/files/artificial.jpg?3140817636037500562"></div>
              <div class="col"><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2503/1376/files/artificial.jpg?3140817636037500562"></div>
              <div class="col"><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2503/1376/files/artificial.jpg?3140817636037500562"></div>
              <div class="col"><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2503/1376/files/artificial.jpg?3140817636037500562"></div>
              <div class="col"><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2503/1376/files/artificial.jpg?3140817636037500562"></div>
   </div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I still don't understand what i did wrong but thank you. Was it the flex-wrap?